# Как взять переменную из одного класса и переместить в другой без наследования?

Tags: java

Есть один класс А, который берёт из текстовика данные и обрабатывает из в два массива. И есть класс B, в котором слушатель берёт из текстового поля число и умножает на данные из класса А. Как можно передать переменные из класса А в класс В без наследования?

Comment: Нужно получать переменные именно из **класса**, а не из **объекта** класса?

Comment: @Byulent а в чём разница будет?

Comment: может, передать как параметр метода?

Comment: Не вариант сделать нужные переменные класса А статичными? Или сделать геттеры?
Причём тут наследование?

Comment: @DenisShestopalov: Если разница между «переменной» в классе и в объекте вызывает вопросы, у меня для вас плохие новости.

Answer (score 2):

Просто создайте переменную хранящую экземпляр класса A и конструктор класса B и в конструкторе передайте этот экземпляр класса на хранение в вашей переменной таким образом:

```html
private A aClass;


public B(A aClass) {
  this.aClass = aClass;
}
```

А в классе A либо сделайте доступ к вашим данным public, либо создайте для них геттеры.
А дальше вы можете использовать эти данные в любом методе класса B.

Comment: Давайте не будет давать сразу плохих ответов в части "доступ к вашим данным public", чтоб не учить человека плохому. Ни в коем случае не делаем поля класса public. Остальное так и есть.